# Interpretation of skewness tensor in information geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, fisher-information, information-geometry

In many textbooks about the information geometry (for instance, "Information Geometry with Applications" by Amari), authors emphasize that *statistical manifold* is described by tripple $\{\mathcal{M},G,T\}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is manifold, $G$ is metric on it and $T$ is third-order tensor, which is called *skewness tensor*. The authors also emphasize the difference between this structure and the Riemannian structure $\{\mathcal{M},G\}$.

**My question:** the tensor $T_{ijk}$ is symmetric, whereas in physics I know only one third-order tensor, *torsion tensor*, which is anti-symmetric. How should I interpret the third order symmetric tensor? What is the most suitable physical analogy for this tensor?

**Additional info:** statistical manifolds appear during the study of distance between probability measures. For family of probability measures $p=p(x,\xi)$, where $x$ corresponds to random variable and $\xi$ corresponds to parameters ($\xi$ is vector!), there is a unique metric tensor, defined by
$$g_{ij}=\int dx\,p(x,\xi)\frac{\partial\ln p(x,\xi)}{\partial \xi_i}\frac{\partial\ln p(x,\xi)}{\partial \xi_j},$$
and there is a unique skewness tensor defined by
$$T_{ijk}=\int dx\,p(x,\xi)\frac{\partial\ln p(x,\xi)}{\partial \xi_i}\frac{\partial\ln p(x,\xi)}{\partial \xi_j}\frac{\partial\ln p(x,\xi)}{\partial \xi_k}.$$

In his book, Amari introduces the third-order tensor via the concept of dual connections. Let two vectors, $A$ and $B$. Let $\langle A,B\rangle$ is the scalar product of this two vectors. Let two symmetric affince connections $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma^*$. Let $\Pi$ and $\Pi^*$ are parallel transport operations w.r.t such connections. So, we have
$$\langle A,B\rangle =\langle \Pi A, \Pi^*B\rangle.$$
Next, the skewness tensor is
$$T_{ijk}=\Gamma_{ijk}^*-\Gamma_{ijk}.$$

**Note:** I understand that this question may very specific and there are not lot of details, but it corresponds to my current understanding.